# Selenium Webdriver with Java for OBIEE Dashboard Application

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, obiee

I'm new to testing and trying to automate an OBIEE Dashboard application using Selenium Webdriver with Java. But, the problem is, the object identifiers I'm using (class, xpath, etc.) are dynamically generated, which leads to failure of my test case. Is there any way to overcome this? The scope of my test case is limited to testing the UI only.

Answer (score 1):

My advice? Consider if you really, really, need to be using Java/Selenium approach.

A lot of OBIEE testing is better done at the logical layer using `nqcmd` or ODBC calls into the BI Server. If you really need to test the front end then visual testing is a generally more successful approach. The new Baseline Validation Tool covers both of these. 
You can read more detail here:

- http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/01/automated-regression-testing-for-obiee/
- http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/05/visual-regression-testing-of-obiee-with-phantomcss/
- http://www.slideshare.net/themoff/smarter-regression-testing-for-obiee-ukoug-15
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMrspsqW0qM

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the Generated XPaths as they may be not accurate.
for Example: You want to select this Div

```
<div class='blueBtn'>Click Me</div>
```

the XPath generated will be **//div[@class='blueBtn']**

This may select the first one but if this div is repeatable under another.
You may need to adjust the XPath to select what exactly you want.
So we may be adjust it to be **//div[@class='blueBtn' and position()='2']**

It's recommended to use the IDs of the elements as they are granted to be unique.

I hope this could help.

Comment: Yes, I am using Ids. And this is working for some time. The problem arises  if some new element is added to that page as a modification or enhancement. Since, the UI of the OBIEE applications are handled by the tool, the XPath given earlier changes and the Test Case starts giving an error.